# Cannot find name 'LinkedInLoginScopes' in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, linkedin-api, ionic-native

I have taken the coding reference from the [https://www.djamware.com/post/5971421e80aca7414e78a658/ionic-3-angular-4-and-cordova-linkedin-authentication-tutorial][1]
At this point of code, I'm getting an error

```
scopes: LinkedInLoginScopes[] = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];
```

Error messages is

> Cannot find name 'LinkedInLoginScopes'.

Comment: can you be more specific where or at what action its giving error

Comment: I'm getting the error at `LinkedInLoginScopes`

Comment: can you show your ts file code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to import LinkedInLoginScopes  from native/linkedIn

```js
import { LinkedIn, LinkedInLoginScopes } from '@ionic-native/linkedin';
```

and declare or use it before constructor....
If your still not getting it take a look into [This page](https://github.com/didinj/ionic3-angular4-cordova-linkedin-auth/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: can you also say me how can I get the profile picture from linkedin.

Comment: dont know but you can set up what information you can request to  linkedin while login ...pleae check in that way